# Adding checkbox in signup form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a signup form which needs an checkbox for terms service. I forgot to add that column during the initial scaffold. I do not what do after .Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For that you can add a new migration to add a new column as boolean field to your users table.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

```
rails g migration AddTermsAcceptedToUsers
```

It will create a migration file in your `db/migrate` folder. Now you need to add the code to it.

```
class AddTermsAcceptedToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :terms_accepted, :boolean, :default => false
  end
end
```

Then do `rake db:migrate`.

Now your users table is having a column as `terms_accepted`. Then add it as `attr_accesible`.

```
attr_accessible :terms_accepted.
```

Now use this field and show it as checkbox in the registration page.

```
<%= f.check_box :terms_accepted%>
```

Comment: In Rails 4 no more attr_accessible. If you want to use it - add protected_attributes gem to Gemfile

Answer (score 1):

You can create an attribute acessor for the terms and conditions field in the model.
For example

```
class User < ActiveRecod::Base
attr_accessor :terms_and_conditions
end
```

and in form

```
<%=form_for(@user) do |f|%>
<%=f.check_box :terms_and_conditions %>
<% end %>
```

**Or**

---

You can take the help of "acceptance" method of active record. Please check the 
method in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

This validation is very specific to web applications and this 'acceptance' does not need to be recorded anywhere in your database (if you don't have a field for it, the helper will just create a virtual attribute).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :terms_and_conditions, acceptance: true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To add/update to Bachans' answer, in Rails 4 you'd do:

```
# User Controller
  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :terms_accepted)
    end
```

instead of

```
# User model
attr_accessible :terms_accepted
```

I hope that works!